# Cannot get vue-router to work

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

Got this working with a single page. It's when I introduce `vue-router` that nothing will render.

In `main.js`, if I return `app.js` with sample text and few edits; it renders fine with no issues. Seems it has to do with how I'm instantiating `vue-router`. Also, no console errors in my environment.

**main.js**

```
define(function(require) {
    'use strict';
    var Vue = require('vue');
    var VueRouter = require('vue-router');
    var App = require('app');

    var Foo = { template: '<div>oijsdfoijsdoifjdsf</div>' }
    var Bar = { template: '<div>bar</div>' }

    Vue.use(VueRouter);

    var routes = [
      { path: '/aaa', component: Foo },
      { path: '/bbb', component: Bar }
    ]

    var router = new VueRouter({
      routes: routes 
    });

    return new Vue({
        el: '#vue',
        router: router,
        render: function(h) {
            h(App);
        }
    });
});
```

**app.js**

```
define(function(require) {
    'use strict';

    var Vue = require('vue');

    return new Vue({
        template: '<div id="vue"><router-view></router-view></div>'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, you can change your router configuration to:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    base: __dirname, // or '/'
    routes: routes
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined a root route, e.g. `/`. So you wouldn't see any component render at `/`. Can you navigate to `/aaa` and see something? Also, shouldn't those route components be passed to `Vue.component`?